# not able to use leaflet-realtime plugin with angular5 and ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, leaflet

Not able to use leaflet-realtime plugin in ionic3 & angular 5  application

importing `import leaflet from 'leaflet';` like this

once I try to use real-time like below code

```
leaflet.realtime({
    url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 3 * 1000,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return leaflet.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions)
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

giving me WebKit error saying realtime is not a property of leaflet

how can I use leaflet plugins in ionic3 applications?

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late but i needed the same recently so here a working example, hope to help someone :

*some.page.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-realtime';
```

> Here @Component

```
export class SomePage {

    map: any;
    realtime: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {

        // Initiate the map
        this.map = L.map('mapRT');

        // Start fetching realtime data
        this.realtime = L.realtime({
                url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
                crossOrigin: true,
                type: 'json'
            }, {
                interval: 3 * 1000
            }).addTo(this.map);

        var map = this.map;
        var realtime = this.realtime;

        this.realtime.on('update', function() {
            map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});
        });

        // Map layout
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.map);

    }


    ionViewWillLeave() {
        this.realtime.stop();
        this.map.remove();
    }

}
```